# Can I see server logs or something equivalent on AppHarbor?

Tags: appharbor

I just pushed my app to appharbor. I don't need full-on google analytics (and I can't use it since mostly my app is about dynamically creating rss feeds) but would just like to get a general idea how often my site is being hit and the types of urls that people are hitting.

Normally I would just keep an eye on the severlog but that doesn't seem to be available on appharbor. How can I get something equivalent?

Comment: You can probably do something similar to the [Stackoverflow view counter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87092/dissecting-the-stack-overflow-views-counter)

Comment: @friism a) Not from rss feeds. b) that is solving a completely different problem.

Answer (score 3):

I  recently turned on the [logentries](https://logentries.com/) add-on available in Appharbor and it has been a godsend for solving some server-side errors on my asp mvc 3 app.  Extending my code to log routing requests would be a simple few lines of code.